# CSV file to a web page in Joomla 2.5

Tags: html, database, csv, joomla2.5

I have a 20Mb `.csv` file which I want to turn into a database, which is browsable and searchable through a public web page.

What would be the easiest way to do this?

I would prefer to use as much ready made components as possible and as little coding as possible...

How to do it using Joomla 2.5?

Answer (score 0):

I'd import the data using phpMyAdmin or similar and then use ChronoForms to build a search form and display the results.

References:
https://www.interspire.com/support/kb/questions/851/Overcoming+file+size+limits+when+uploading+SQL+files+to+phpMyAdmin

Comment: phpMyAdmin manages to import only about 10000 lines of 300000 on the csv until it throws an error.

Comment: Instead Chronoforms i ended up using JooDatabase which i a lot easier to configure to a usable state